# Can Garageband Loops be removed after removing Garageband?

Tags: macos, catalina, audio, imovie, garageband

I have just removed Garageband Loops via System Information > Manage; these remained after I'd uninstalled Garageband using AppCleaner.

Can I remove them manually or will this impact other functionality in the system?

Answer (score 1):

You can safely remove the GarageBand loops. Note: These loops can also be used by Logic.

Remember - should you want to use GarageBand in the future, the loops can be re-downloaded any time.

<sub>Edit in light of benwiggy's comment.</sub>

Comment: They are also used by Logic, of course.